# Как изменить название ячеек в Excel?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

```py
col = [] #задаю названия колонок
for i in range(1,22):
    col.append(f"Пункт №{i}")

row = [] #задаю названия строчек (названия такие же будут, как и у колонок)
for j in range(1,22):
    row.append(f"Пункт №{j}")

pd.DataFrame(matrix).to_excel("graph.xlsx",startcol=1,startrow=1,header=col,index=row)
```

[image: описание]

Благодаря `header=col` колонки отобразились с нужным названием, но `index=row` не вывел нужные названия, а просто вывел цифры и числа от 0 до 20, что не нужно. Как исправить это и вместо этих чисел установить такие же названия, как и у колонок?

Можно добавить отдельно этот столбик: `pd.DataFrame(row).to_excel("graph.xlsx",startcol=0,startrow=0,header=False,index=False)`, но тогда всё остальное не сохранится.
[image: описание2]

Comment: Читаем доку  index:     bool, default True  Write row names (index).  index=False. Добавьте ещё одну колонку с Вашими названиями

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно не добавлять столбик, а просто сделать индекс фрейма из списка. И по умолчанию, он будет выведен в ексель

```
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix)
df.index = col
df.to_excel("graph.xlsx", header=col)
```